# Mocha testing schema with .validate() does not return

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongoose, mocha.js

Currently I'm trying write some schema tests, and I have the following schema:

```
const ItemSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  _id : mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
  price : {type : Number},
  name : {type : String, required : true, trim : true},
  urlPath : {type : String, required : true, unique : true, trim : true},
  creationDate   : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
  lastModDate : {type : Date, default : Date.now},
}, {
  toJSON: { virtuals: true }
});
```

The properties `urlPath` and `name` are required.

My test file looks like the following:

```
 describe('validation', () => {
    it('should be invalid if name is missing', function(done){
      let item = new Item({urlPath : "item-1-urlPath"});
      item.validate(function(err){
        if(!err) done('should not be here');
        expect(err.name).to.eql('ValidationError');
        expect(err.errors).to.have.property('name');
        done();
      });
    })
  })
```

I always get this error:

> Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves.

but when I validate the for missing `urlPath` like this:

```
let item = new Item({name : "item-1"});
```

everything seems to be fine

**UPDATE**

the middleware I'm using (description in th answer)

```
ItemSchema.pre('validate', async function() {
  var item    = this;
  let urlPath = item.urlPath;
  // only if it has been modified (or is new)
  if (!item.isModified('urlPath')) return Promise.resolve();
  urlPath = await [HERE_I_AM_CALLING_A_PROMISE_FUNCTION]
  item.urlPath = urlPath;
});
```

- nodejs : 8.1.1
- mongoose : 5.1.3
- typescript : 2.9.1
- system :  ubuntu 16.04

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem came due to a middleware which I updated in the description, this middleware is calling the database asynchronously, whereby I'm just testing the schema and cant query the database without a connection.

I think this happened due to a connection error, which takes more than 2 seconds to be thrown.

Comment: What was the solution that you used? Im struggling with this right now as well